# How do move div with mouse pointer on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="moveAble" style="position: absolute;">
<div class="info"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1498221863/Jodis_Gifts_logo_hi_res_normal.jpg" alt="info" /></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('div.moveAble').mousemove(function(e){
            var y = e.pageY;
            var x = e.pageX;
            $('div.moveAble').css({'top': y}); 
            $('div.moveAble').css({'left': x});

      });
    });
```

Above code is not working properly, as i move mouse pointer it move in bottom and right direction only and not top and left. and div movement is also not smooth. 
How do i fix this to make it work.

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/434/)

Comment: You have to use .animate to make smooth moment

Comment: The problem is that you're handling the mousemove event on the div itself, but when you move the mouse up to the left it isn't over the div anymore.

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com - No you don't: there are plenty of sites with smooth movement that don't use jQuery at all and so don't use `.animate()`.

Comment: instead of `$('div.moveAble').mousemove` use `$(document).mousemove`

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/435/ ?

Comment: @nnnnnn but he is using jQuery right now. that's why I suggested him.

Comment: @rps - caching the selector and using one call to `.css()` is even better: http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/440/

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com - I was objecting to your phrasing "have to use". With or without jQuery it is not the only way to get smooth movement.

Comment: @nnnnnn ok you are the master. now happy???

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com - It's not about being seen to win the argument, it is about not having incorrect information posted here. If you convince me that your original statement is true I will happily acknowledge it. If you accept my point we can both delete all of our (related) comments...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose this is the effect you wanted  http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/440/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $moveable = $('.moveAble');
  $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $moveable.css({'top': e.pageY,'left': e.pageX});
  });
});
```

Thanks to [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) for mentioning the caching of `$moveable`

Comment: It is not necessary to bind event to document. You can calculate mouse offset and figure out mouse direction and move image.

Comment: @antindexer, It's best to use `document` for `mousemove` events, but to enable/disable listeners based on another user input (e.g. `mousedown` and `mouseup`).

Comment: @antindexer, the image also won't move along with the cursor until `mousemove` event is triggered for that image (i.e. the mouse moves across that image)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('div.moveAble').mousemove(function(e){
            var y = e.pageY;
            var x = e.pageX;
            $('.moveAble').css('top', y-20).css('left', x-20);
      });
    });
```

Look this `$('.moveAble').css('top', y-20).css('left', x-20);`

Your mouse is just at border, so you need to shift it.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/436/

Comment: This works better than the original version, but if you move the mouse quickly it will still move off the div and so the div will stop following the mouse. (An effect that is, possibly, desirable?)

Comment: Yes, i've seen that, it coould do better to center the mouse on div with "$('.moveAble').css('top', y - ($(this).height() / 2)).css('left', x- ($(this).width() / 2)); " (http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/442/), but if the user moves quickly it's still the same.